# Efficiently parallelizing PyTorch neural network training with multiprocessing.Pool on remote server with CUDA

Tags: python, ubuntu, pytorch

I am working on training a neural network using the PyTorch framework in Python and would like to parallelize the training process using multiprocessing.Pool. The training data is large and I am using a remote server running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with a specific CUDA version to take advantage of GPU acceleration. I want to ensure that the training process is as efficient as possible and that the results are properly saved to disk.

Specifically, I have the following questions:

1. How can I efficiently load the training data into memory while using multiprocessing.Pool to parallelize the training process?
2. Are there any specific considerations I need to take into account when using multiprocessing.Pool with PyTorch and CUDA on a remote server?
3. How can I ensure that the results are properly saved to disk while using multiprocessing.Pool to parallelize the training process?
   Tags: python, pytorch, multiprocessing, gpu, cuda, parallel-processing

Additional information:

- The remote server has a specific CUDA version (e.g., CUDA 10.1) and PyTorch version (e.g., PyTorch 1.7.1).
- The training data is stored in a large dataset (e.g., HDF5 format) that is too large to fit into memory all at once.
- The neural network architecture and training script are already implemented and functional, but currently run in serial on a local machine.
- I am familiar with basic Python and PyTorch concepts, but am relatively new to parallel processing and CUDA.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.